# how to access labelfrom static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, static, webmethod

i am new to .net
I want to access a label from the static method
actually i want to change the operator label name based on the first 4digits of mobile number
here i am using autocomplete extender to do that
i want call the label from the that static method

Here's my code

design

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtnumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtnumber"
     MinimumPrefixLength="4" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="4" CompletionInterval="1000"
     ServiceMethod="GetCity" >
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

<asp:Label ID="operator" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

code

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void GetCity(string prefixText)
{


    operator..text = "Airtel";

}
```

is the way i am is correct if it is please suggest the answer. if not please suggest the way which i could achieve it

Comment: Why does `GetCity` need to be static?  You are probably setting it to static because you dont understand the difference between instances and static classes/methods.  You should avoid making things static in general.

Comment: IF iam not using static i am unable to access that method i have checked using checkpoint

Comment: The `ServiceMethod` does not need to be static as in [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0400__Ajax/UsingtheAutoCompleteExtenderwithaWebServiceMethod.htm)